# Alias not working

Tags: ssh, alias, bash-alias

I have an alias that does an `ssh` into a machine and executes 1 line of code as following:

```
alias posts-update= 'ssh user@host.com "cd /var/www/blog/posts && git pull"'
```

This works perfectly if executed manually but if I try to use the `posts-update` alias, it does nothing and prints nothing

Comment: Do you really have a space between the `=` and the opening quote? http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-alias

Comment: Note that the command can be written in a slightly more straightforward way: `ssh user@host git -C /var/www/blog/posts pull`.

Comment: @DanielAndersson: The `-C` option was added recently (in 1.8, I think?) so it might not always work. [I've seen systems with git 1.6…]

Comment: @glennjackman ya, somehow managed to missed that.

Comment: @grawity: All right, I mostly use Mercurial in a similar way that has had such a switch for a long time. I looked it up for Git in the manual on my local system as I wrote the above, since I just assumed it would have a similar switch :-) . [Stack Overflow has a question that confirms that it is quite recent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5083224/445621); only since 1.8.5, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space after the `=` in your command, splitting the parameter into two:

- `'posts-update='`
- `'ssh user@host.com "cd /var/www/blog/posts && git pull"'`

This causes `alias` to alias `posts-update` to *nothing* (as there is nothing following the `=`). It should also print an error message about the second parameter, which doesn't have a `=` in it so `alias` thinks it's an existing alias name to be described.